# navigation drawer : Gradle doesn't build

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, navigation-drawer, androidx

I want to make navigation drawer but `gradle` can not build.

[This errors!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTR4F.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your online has trouble,just try more times,or change your net, or restart your AS.

Comment: i couldn't solve it. i use vpn . and its the first time i use navigation activity. im beginner .